# Importing CSV files to SAS without specifying formats

Tags: sas

I have a very large CSV file with over a million observations and 170 variables that generally looks like the following:

VariableA, VariableB, VariableC
1,2,”01/01/2024”
,Yes, 0
1,1,

I am interested in cleaning my data using SAS but I keep getting errors when importing the file even when I’m specifying the formats to characters. The only solution I’ve found so far is to specify length, format and informat for all variables in a data step, which resulted in over 765 lines of code—all that to just import one file.

It seems like R can handle this easily by using read_csv from the readr package. Is SAS going to need an extremely long code to execute something that R can do in one line of code?

Comment: What errors do you get with `proc import`? What happens if you import it with Enterprise Guide's import option?

Comment: Those non ASCII quote characters will cause trouble.

Comment: I have net seen R do any better of a job at reading in CSV files into the proper type of variables without the user having to intervene.  And the syntax in R is much more cryptic and cramped than using SAS data steps.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I read this one line of csv in both SAS and Python, both worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If does not take that many lines to write a program to read a simple delimited file.  But it does take at least 170 words to give 170 variables unique names.  But if you just want to use simple names like VAR1, VAR2, etc. then you can read a CSV file with 170 fields per line treating each variable as character with a maximum length of 50 bytes with this simple program. (If the file does not have a header row then remove the FIRSTOBS=2 option).

```
data want;
   infile 'myfile.csv' dsd truncover firstobs=2;
   input (var1-var170) (:$50.);
run;
```

And if you do want to write your own code it does not take much more.  **Most variables do not need to have either an INFORMAT nor a FORMAT attached to them.**  Take the examples in your post:

The first 3 look like character strings (not sure why the third one has space and and extra digit in it. The next 2 are numbers, but the second one will need to use the MMDDYY (or perhaps DDMMYY) informat to convert that string with slashes into a date value. And it will need to have a date type format attached to it. Preferable something like DATE or YYMMDD to avoid the confusion that the style in the CSV file will cause.

```
data want;
  infile cards dsd truncover;
  input (Str1-Str3) (:$20.) num1 date :mmddyy. str4 :$3. str5 :$10. num2 num3;
  format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
VariableA, VariableB, VariableC 1,2,"01/01/2024" ,Yes, 0 1,1,
;
```

Results
[image]

You can try letting PROC IMPORT make its best GUESS how to read the file.  You should get results similar to the GUESSES that your R package would make.

```
proc import file='myfile.csv' dbms=csv out=want replace;
  guessingrows=max;
run;
```

If you don't like how PROC IMPORT guesses then try some other tool.  Like [%csv2ds()](https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/csv2ds.sas) macro.  That will generally do a better job of guessing, and it also has ways for you to override the guesses.

You should also make sure the CSV file does not have any end of line characters embedded into the header or other character field.  For example by checking how many fields are on each line.  So if you expect there to be 170 you might run something like this to show the first 10 lines that do NOT have 170 values on them.

```
data _null_;
  if nbad >= 10 then stop;
  infile 'myfile.csv' ;
  input;
  nwords=countw(_infile_,',','mq');
  if nwords=170 then delete;
  nbad+1;
  put (_n_ nbad nwords) (=);
  list;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Tom's answer, one way you could read it in with a data step while maintaining the variable names is by grabbing the variable names first, then saving them into a macro variable. You can pass that list of names right into a data step that reads the raw values.

If you do run into any errors, you'll have a lot more control on how to fix it compared to `proc import`.

```
data _null_;
    infile "have.csv" lrecl=32767 length=len;
    input line $varying32767. len;
    call symputx('vars', transtrn(line, ',', ' '));
    stop;
run;

data want;
    length &vars $500.;
    infile "have.csv" dlm=',' firstobs=2 dsd;
    input &vars;
run;
```